# What are the requirements for growing liana vines in Terraria?

Tags: terraria

I have noticed that [liana vines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liana) spawn from dirt blocks in natural caves and even player made caves given it has a light source.

I have tried to create a "curtain" of those above ground level, but they do not seem to grow.
What are the requirements for vines to start growing and what affects the speed of growth?

Comment: I've played Terraria, but I'm not sure what Liana is, and it doesn't appear in either the official or the wikia wiki. Could you elaborate, or include an image or something?

Comment: Yeah, I used wrong term myself, Vine is the correct one. Could have helped me alot in my search too. I will keep the title, so others who make the same mistake as me can find something.

Comment: Problem with the term vine, there is also a vine object. So it is all pretty confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean the [vines](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Vines#Vines), as you speak of dirt blocks, and the vines grow from those. They do look like [liane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liana).

The dirt block needs to have grass on it. And grass spreads from other grassy dirt blocks. Or, you can use [grass seeds](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Grass_Seeds), or the [Staff of Regrowth](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Staff_of_Regrowth).

The only requirement I can find is just a grassy dirt block. Sunlight, underground/aboveground. It all doesn't matter.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that below a certain depth grass does not naturally occur or spread if planted. The vines also don't grow too far down either.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, it appears that vines were what I was looking for. Do you know if seeds can be planted in bottom side of a placed block?

Comment: yes, you can plant grass seeds on the ceiling of dirt blocks.

Comment: I never really played around with deep planting of grass tbh. So I'm not totally sure.

Comment: @TheBW Technically, grass occupies an entire block, so you aren't actually planting grass on the "ceiling" of any block.  It may look that way because only the ceiling is exposed.  You can plant grass on any dirt block anywhere, but as has been mentioned before it behaves differently underground than it does above ground.  Use a depth meter to tell where that 0 elevation boundary is.